# Intel folder not seen in SDK manager

Tags: emulation, intel

Hi I am just starting to learn about Android and I have everything installed(I think), but cannot open emulator(shows: [2013-12-11 15:59:29 - SDK Manager] Error: null) - so I am looking for the Intel 86 thing, but it is not even showing available for download - see below - what am I missing? I have a newer MBP (10.7)

Comment: It should be under the Extras folder.  Be sure you have the latest version of the SDK Tools installed.  See: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-2

Comment: Hi, I have 18 and 19 installed, under the Extras folder it just says Android Support Library, and it is all installed as well.

Comment: 18 and 19 are Android API versions.  The SDK Tools version should be 22.3.  There should be about 12 items under the Extras folder including the Intel x86 HAXM.

Comment: Hi Clay, thanks for writing - In my manager it says Android SDK Tools 22.3 installed, in the extras folder it says SDK>extras>android>support>notice, readme,samples,source properties,V4,V7,V13 and so on - when I search for the work Intel, nothing comes up -do I need to add something else>? I am trying to instal ADT 22.3, but it won't load, so many this is wrong too?

Answer (score 0):

You can see this folder here C:\Users\your_computer_name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager.
AppData is a hidden folder, so if you don't see it, go in view option and allow hidden operating system files